# Use WSO2 Identity Server as an aggregate for one or more LDAP servers

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Can you use WSO2 IdentityServer as a LDAP aggregate (also known as a LDAP proxy)?

For example, I have 2 ActiveDirectory servers and I want to search for a user who could be on either server. Usually I would need to execute separate LDAP searches on each ActiveDirectory.

To save us executing a search on each AD, could we configure IS to use both AD's as external LDAP user stores. Then if we did a LDAP search against IS it would search both AD's and return the results from both servers.

Due to the first answer, I need to add that I can connect the Active Directory servers as user stores. But what I can't get working is using a LDAP search against IS to find a user in these user stores. I get back a list of LDAP objects but there none of the users are listed.

David/

Answer (score 1):

You can configure multiple user stores with wso2 IS

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Working+with+User+Stores
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS450/Configuring+Secondary+User+Stores

Hope this helps

Comment: I understand i can configure primary and secondary user stores, and i have this  working. But what i can't get working is using a ldap search against IS to find a user in these stores.